# How to get Cloudwatch Logs to display most recent event first, instead of first event in the stream, by default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

When I open a specific log stream in the Cloudwatch console, it automatically opens the page with the first event in that stream by default, meaning that to see the most recent log event on that stream, I either have to keep loading and scrolling to the bottom until I reach it, or use the absolute time/date filters to show only the last few minutes (which are both time consuming).

Previously, when I opened a log stream, the logs would automatically load from the bottom up, so the most recent log event would be displayed at the bottom when I open the page.

How can I change the default behaviour back? I understand I can do this with CLI but this is for front-end users with no technical/CLI knowledge and only access to logs via the console.

For example, I navigate to Cloudwatch > Log groups, then select a Log group to see all Log streams. On this page, for the most recent log stream it shows 2024-01-08 05:28:41 (UTC+00:00) in the 'Last event time' column. So when I click on that stream, I expect to be able to see the log Message posted at 05:28:41, but instead the page opens with the first log event in that stream from when the code started executing (at 02:02:02).

Comment: You can not, you will have to use cloudwatch log insights and sort descending on timestamp field.